# How to specify a specific element in a web page using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, find, element

I need some elements in a web page that I can't see their ID in developer tools:

```
<input type="text" ng-if="!editing" ng-model="item.Price" ng-click="inputFocus()" ts="" required="" placeholder="Price :" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-scope ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
```

I also wanted to use `xpath` but I saw there are several similar elements with the same `xpath`s in the page. So how can I specify the element that I want from the above code?

Comment: If you can't see the ID in the HTML, the element has no ID.

Comment: @Valga: So what is the other unique identifier for elements? Or how can I combine some of them to specify a unique element?

Answer (score 1):

There are other location strategies, you can locate elements not only by [ID](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-id), the other options are in:

- by [Name](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-name) - the value of [`name` HTML attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_name.asp)

  ```
  not applicable because your element doesn't have name attribute
  ```
- by [XPath](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) - you can use arbitrary [XPath expression](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) to locate your element like:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@placeholder, 'Price')]")
  ```
- by [Link Text](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text) `<a href="http://example.com">Example Domain</a>` here the text is `Example Domain`

  ```
  not applicable because your element is not a hyperlink
  ```
- by [Tag Name](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_tagname.asp) - your HTML tag, in your case it's `input`

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_tag_name("input")
  ```
- by [Class Name](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-class-name) - value of the [HTML `class` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_class.asp)

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_class_name("ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-scope ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required")
  ```
- by [CSS Selector](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors) - with the help of [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors)

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[ng-model=item.Price]")
  ```

The easiest and the fastest way which allow you to uniquely identify the element is the best one.

The most powerful of the aforementioned location approaches is XPath, but it's the slowest and the most resource intensive one.